SQlite3 || How to use return for select in a function
I started learning js relatively recently. I have a function that should return the search result from the SQlite3 table. but because of the asynchrony, it outputs the result before it has found any information and reached the return, because of this, an undefindet is output.
funcion find_info() {
    db.all('SELECT * FROM test', (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {return console.log('error in search information');}
    
        // console.log(rows)
        return rows;
    });
}

console.log(find_info) // undefined

I expect to receive the answer and the result of the columns. I tried to put the answer in a variable and then output it to return

Create a Promise and await for it to get the result when it’s ready. Resolve it in the callback.

Спасибо, действительно работает
